# Cross-compiling with OpenSSL for Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile the oauth-utils
http://mir.dnsalias.com/oss/oauth/start
for Windows from Ubuntu.  I have compiled it on Windows before
(a few months back), but wanted to try cross-compiling.

I got openssl build using mingw32 ok, and put
libssl.a and libcrypto.a in the right place.  The linker is now
finding the libraries (yay!) but I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaac): undefined reference to `_CreateDCA@16'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xab9): undefined reference to `_CreateCompatibleDC@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xacc): undefined reference to `_GetDeviceCaps@8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xadc): undefined reference to `_GetDeviceCaps@8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaf4): undefined reference to `_CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb04): undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb18): undefined reference to `_GetObjectA@12'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb81): undefined reference to `_BitBlt@36'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb8c): undefined reference to `_GetBitmapBits@12'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbe5): undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbec): undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbf6): undefined reference to `_DeleteDC@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xc00): undefined reference to `_DeleteDC@4'
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if one remove everything between

```
static void readscreen(void)
{
#if !defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINCE) && !defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32_CYGWIN)
```

and

```
#endif /* !OPENSSL_SYS_WINCE */
}
```

in rand_win.c, that building works.  I'm not 100% sure how safe removing this is.

Answer (score 4):

Link with Gdi32.lib

Comment: This fixed linking to openssl for me in mingw! No need to change anything in rand_win.c which is the current accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! Also fixed similar linking errors using libcrypto and the CommonCrypto framework in cocotron

Answer (score 2):

Which version of OpenSSL are you trying to compile?
In general, I have found version 1.0 and newer with MinGW-w64 to work great.
See for example the [OpenSSL cross-compilation for Windows](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2011/12/21/openssl-for-windows/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding -mwindows to your link command?